# Send every properties with postMessage

Tags: javascript, object, properties, clone, postmessage

I have an object to which I defined a custom property with `Object.defineProperty` like that:

```
Object.defineProperty(myObject,prop,{
    get:function(){
       return something(prop);
    }
})
```

But when I send this object to a Worker with postMessage(), the received clone doesn't have this special property I created, so is there any way to make it sent with the other properties ?